# how to create React search with multiple fields name

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

i am working on  autocomplete with reactjs and react material-ui. Now its working on only one field name **symbol** but i want its work on multiple fields name like **"symbol and name"** Here is my working code and API response. API response filed name **return row.symbol;**

**React search code**

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Autocomplete from "./Autocomplete";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
    const style = {
      flexGrow: 1,
    };

    export class SearchScripComponent extends Component<any, any> {
      constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          searchArray: [],
          message: null,
        };
        this.searchScripData = this.searchScripData.bind(this);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.searchScripData(this.requesDATA2());
      }

      requesDATA2() {
        let data1 = { symbolOrName: "TATA" };
        return data1;
      }

      searchScripData(searchScrip: any) {
        ApiService.searchScripDataList(searchScrip).then((res) => {
          this.setState({ searchArray: res.data.data });
        });
      }
      render() {
        const suggestions = this.state.searchArray.map((row: any) => {
          return row.symbol;
        });
        return <Autocomplete suggestions={suggestions} />;
      }
    }

    export default SearchScripComponent;
```

**API Data**

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "scripId": 299,
            "symbol": "TATAGLOBAL",
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 520,
            "symbol": "TATAYODOGA",
            "name": "ttp"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 1195,
            "symbol": "TATASPONGE",
            "name": "eer"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 30,
            "symbol": "TATASTLBSL",
            "name": "qwer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you filtering at JS level or at api level?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan API Level

Comment: Then you should share the API level code :)